# sequelize: relations in both directions needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two existing tables in my database: "user" with the columns "id" and "depId" and "department" with "id" and "name".  (user.depId ist the foreign key for department.id)

Now I'd like to create a sequelize model for this.

I already added this

```
User.belongsTo (Department, { foreignKey: 'depId', targetKey: 'id'});
```

Do I have to add this also:

```
Department.HasMany(User)
```

or is one direction enough to work properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **sequelize: relations in both directions needed?**

Depends

---

So here we go :

> ```
> User.belongsTo (Department, { foreignKey: 'depId', targetKey: 'id'});
> ```
>
> This will help you to get **Department via User** via sequelize
>   association ,

---

> ```
> Department.HasMany(User)
> ```
>
> But this what you need if you want to get **User via Department** via
>   sequelize association

So define any one of it if you just gonna needed one , but **best practice is to define both way.**

Comment: So this should work for my example:

User.belongsTo (Department, { foreignKey: 'depId', targetKey: 'id'});
Department.hasMany(User, { foreignKey: 'depId', targetKey: 'id'})
?

Comment: @Franken , try `User.belongsTo(Department,{foreignKey : 'depId' });
Department.hasMany(User,{foreignKey:'depId'});`